# Unable to add the Signature saved as Image in the ContentDocument in the PDF created using VF and Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am using canvas to capture the **User Signature** in an **LWC Component**.

After capturing the signature, I store that in the *ContentDocument* object and try to overlay it on the VisualForce Page which is used to generate a pdf file.

**APEX Code**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static void generateServiceReportPDF(String recordId, string data, boolean optin, String customerName) {
    try{

        // Signature Saving Block
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.PathOnClient = 'CustomerSignature_' + recordId + '_' + System.now().getTime() + '.png';
        cv.Title = 'CustomerSignature_' + recordId + '_' + System.now().getTime() + '.png';
        cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(data);
        insert cv;
        
        ServiceAppointment serApp = [SELECT AccountId, ParentRecordId FROM ServiceAppointment WHERE id = :recordId and ParentRecordType = 'WorkOrder' limit 1];
        
        Id accountId = serApp.AccountId;
        Id workOrderId = serApp.ParentRecordId;
            
        PageReference pdfPage = new PageReference('/apex/ServiceReportViaApp?id=' + workOrderId + '&signatureId=' + cv.Id + '&customerName=' + customerName);
        Blob pdfBlob;
        pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
        
        // Save the PDF as needed
        ContentVersion cont = new ContentVersion();
        cont.Title = 'Service Report';
        cont.PathOnClient = 'ServiceReport.pdf';
        cont.VersionData = pdfBlob;
        cont.Origin = 'H';
        insert cont;
        
        Id conDocId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :cont.Id].ContentDocumentId;
        
        ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDocId;
        //conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = recordId;
        conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = workOrderId;
        conDocLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
        conDocLink.ShareType = 'V';
        insert conDocLink;
    }
    Catch(Exception e){
        HandleBusinessException.captureError('GenerateServiceReportViaFSLApp', 'generatePDFMethod', e); 
    }
}
```

**VF Page Codes**

```
<apex:page StandardController="WorkOrder" extensions="ServiceReportViaAppController,TimeZoneController" renderAs="PDF" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" readOnly="false">

<html>
    <body>
        <apex:outputPanel > 
            <table style="width:100%;font-size: 12px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="border:1px solid black;font-size: 12px;width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Customer Name/Sign
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <apex:image url="{!userSignature}" width="150px" height="200px"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
            </table>              
            
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

It generates a pdf with broken image sign at the place of signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Salesforce, like most database systems, one transaction can't see the results of another transaction until the transaction has fully committed. When you call a Visualforce page, it runs in a separate transaction. That means that the Visualforce page that's rendering the PDF can't see the file you just uploaded because that transaction hasn't committed yet. You will need to break this into two transactions, the first to upload the signature, and a separate transaction to render the PDF. Something like this:

```
// JavaScript
saveSignature({fileData}).then((fileId)=>generatePDF({fileId}));
```

The specifics will depend on if you're using Aura or LWC, but the point is that you need to have two methods to generate the PDF.

Comment: I have achieved the required functionality by moving the PDF creation code block to future method and creating Attachments instead of ContentVersion. But thanks for educating us about the root cause.